# using native lib compiled for android in java

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I created simple Jello JNI project in Android studio. There are several .so libs in the corresponding apk file for each architecture:

```
mips
mips64
armabi-v7a
armabi
arm64-v8a
x86
x86_64
```

Is it possible to use .so file from x86_64 folder in my Java application and run it on my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

No. The x86_64 version was compiled for Android and is an ELF64 binary. It is probably linked with Android specific libraries. Even on Linux x64 it should fail to load.